# Understanding a "return something if" python expression

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, boolean-expression, coding-efficiency

Here is some code daily coding problem has stated I should trust how it works.

`def count(node): return count(node.left) + count(node.right) + 1 if node else 0`

It's supposed to recursively go through a tree and count the nodes. The part of the code that looks nonsensical to me is where the if statement is part of the return statement, and it says if node else 0. Is if node really going to evaluate as a Boolean expression.

They also stated that you don't need to understand the code but just to trust that it works. What does anyone gain by code they can't understand? Understanding the code seems like basic competence. Hard to imagine an employer hire someone who can regurgitate code but doesn't understand how said code works.

Comment: Sounds like a bad teacher.

Comment: Oh and hey, welcome to Stack Overflow, and with this attitude you are at the right place indeed, because not just copying snippets from answers on this site but actually trying to understand them and applying what your learn from them yourself is the most effective (and least annoying for others) way to use this site ^^

Comment: @CherryDT yeah it's this website called daily coding problem they send you a programming related interview question everyday. Their explanation regarding binary tree problems was "...It’s important to not get caught up on how this works and just have faith that it works. If you start tracing the recursion, you’re going to needlessly use up time and energy during the interview..." They gave this code snippet then proceeded to tear it apart.

Comment: @CherryDT good to hear because the common attitude today is that things should be understood with no explanation. A lot of code today is so compacted that to a learner it is nonsensical. I'll ask another really hard question. Maybe you can try to answer it.

Comment: A dissenting opinion: if you try to understand everything you see to the fullest extent, you will spend so much time in wonder and awe (if you make progress) or in confusion (if you don't) that you will never get to act on your knowledge. Detail where necessary, but broad strokes will get you farther and faster than a trust-nobody outlook.

Comment: @tucuxi I have a tendency to want to know the exact inner workings of everything. I want to make an OS from scratch so currently I'm awestruck how the computer boots. I'm going to ask a really old question that I've had for 15 or more years regarding GUIs, but I have to wait for the post limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't immediately recognise the language, but if we accept that it is some sort of pythonesq backwards if, then it is a reasonable implementation.

The idea they are trying to push is that you can understand what recursive code it is doing without getting bogged down in the detail of stepping through some complex example.

In this case they are saying "what if you are on a node?" the size of the subtree is the side of the two child subtrees plus 1 for the current node.

This is fine, until you get to a leaf node. You want a leaf node to return the answer 1 - there are no children, just the 1 leaf node. The way they did it was to say "what happens if we follow the children on the leaf?" well then you get a null node.

If the null node returns a count of zero, then the calculation on the leaf node gives 0+0+1 => 1 which is the answer we want.

This also nicely covers the case where the caller calls with an empty tree - the answer should be zero.

You have to do these tests to see if the left and/or right children are null, and it doesn't do each test more than once, it is reasonably efficient for what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was not a fan when this happened to me in school. If a teacher (or another developer for that matter) is going to imply something like that, it's nice to at least have a reference to why it works the way it should.

There is always a chance that's not what they're trying to teach you at the moment and so they're skipping over it for now. But if that is the case, they should have written it differently...

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, it is exactly the opposite - developers should be taught from the very beginning to always try to learn concepts and understand how everything works that they use (if feasible) instead of just blindly trusting it. Otherwise they will never become really effective and won't develop a proper understanding of what their own code does, which makes it very hard to troubleshoot any issues (and issues *will* happen, all the time).

---

**EDIT**: Hm OK with the additional context, I think I understand what they meant. If you get a problem that uses some existing bit of code and the goal is not to find a bug in that code or something like that, then you should probably not try to dissect that code and waste time on that too much but accept it as a black box with a given description and interface and just work with it.

This is of course true, because you don't want to waste time and also when you use a third-party library in real life, you mostly don't first read its code and fully understand it, but you'd read the docs and understand its interface and what it's supposed to do (maybe read its unit tests as a way to learn by example) and that's it, unless you have problems with it that prompt you to dig deeper into how it works in order to understand what is going wrong.

---

About this code in particular: What you see there is a [conditional expression](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/#conditional-expressions-pythons-ternary-operator) which is Python's take on the classic "ternary operator".

It works like this:

```py
<expr_if_true> if <conditional_expr> else <expr_if_false>
```

...and will evaluate to `<expr_if_true>` if `<conditional_expr>` is true, otherwise it will evaluate to `<expr_if_false>`.

Note that most other languages use a different syntax for that:

```cpp
<conditional_expr> ? <expr_if_true> : <expr_if_false>
```

You could argue that Python's syntax is more "natural" to read, though.

So, in your case, the method could be rewritten more explicitly like this:

```py
def count(node):
  if node:
    return count(node.left) + count(node.right) + 1
  else:
    return 0
```

This works by checking whether the given `node` exists (if `node` is `None` then `if node` will not be fulfilled since `None` is a falsy value), and if yes then it returns the sum of the counts of itself (1) and its left and right child nodes. If the `node` doesn't exist, it returns 0. (And if a node doesn't have children, it will be `count(None) + count(None) + 1` which, as we just learned, will evaluate to `0 + 0 + 1` so it'll work too.)

Comment: Ok I wouldn't have guessed it was the ternary operator. It's nice in C because it's unmistakable with the ? Operator. It's interesting they allow that on a return statement in python. I don't think this would fly in Java.

Comment: In Java you can do the same, just with the other syntax: `return node ? count(node.left) + count(node.right) + 1 : 0`

Comment: I guess node is assumed to be Boolean. Thank you for your answer. I remember conditionals being restricted on return statements in Java, maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: No, `node` is probably an object or nothing (`None`). And conditional checks always check for truthyness (in almost all languages it is like that).

Comment: Usually you have everything being truthy except for a very obviously falsy things like `0` and `false` and `None`

Comment: "It's interesting they allow that on a return statement in python" is not a good way of thinking about this.  A `return` statement takes an expression, a ternary operator is an expression - that's absolutely all there is to it, nothing needs to be "allowed" in this specific situation.